# RxJs Observable created from Iterable of promises not updating values each iteration

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, iterator, reactive-programming

I would like to create an RxJS Observable from an iterable like the following:

```
const networkIterableFactory = (resource: string) => {
  let i = 0;
  return {
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
      return {
        next() {
          return {
            done: false,
            value: fetch(resource, {
              mode: 'cors',
            }).then(async response => {
              console.log('i = ', i);
              await throttle(10000); // Do some stuff
              i++;
              return {i: 'i'};
            }),
          };
        },
      };
    },
  };
};

function throttle(ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

let networkIterable = networkIterableFactory('google.com');

let network$ = rxjs.from(networkIterable).pipe(rxjs.operators.take(5));

network$.subscribe(() => console.log('yo!'));
```

Issue is that i prints 5 times as 0.  It seems as though the way that the iterable's iterator saves its state is through updating the outer closure.  rxjs.from just takes the whole iterable as one emmission so a bunch of unresolved promises are returned, but I need the iterator state to be altered by logic within the promise callback.  Is there a way to make the observable wait until the promise resolves before emitting the next item from the iterator?  I would rather avoid using asyncIterable because I don't want to bring in IxRx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the values of your iterable are returned asynchronously, then you should implement `Symbol.asyncIterator` instead of `Symbol.iterator` Try this instead:

```
const networkIterableFactory = (resource: string) => {
  let i = 0;
  return {
    [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
      return {
        next() {
          return fetch(resource, { mode: 'cors' }).then(x => ({ done: false, value: x }));
        },
      };
    },
  };
};

function throttle(ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

let networkIterable = networkIterableFactory('google.com');

let network$ = rxjs.from(networkIterable).pipe(rxjs.operators.take(5));

network$.subscribe(() => console.log('yo!'));
```

**Edit:**

RxJS actually doesn't support Async iterators yet: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1624.

I also tried with an `AsyncGenerator`:

```
const { from } = require('rxjs');

async function* test() {};
const asyncGenerator = test();
from(asyncGenerator);
```

But it throws:

> TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected.
>   You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

So you won't be able to make it with this pattern, I actually believe that RxJS is not suited for "pulling" data like you do with `take` (If this pattern worked, it would end up in an infinite requests loop, even if you only `take` 5 results). It is rather designed to "push" things to whoever listens.

Comment: Yup, that was my first thought, unfortunately rxjs.from does not support asyncIterators.

Comment: Yeah, I think they put this functionality in the IxRx library which I'm unfortunately not in a position to use.  Anyway, just wanted to confirm that this is a dead end, thanks for your help.